# List of tuples of sets to a list of sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, dataset

This is the dataset :

```
data=[(frozenset({'I1'}), frozenset({'I2'})), (frozenset({'I1'}), frozenset({'I3'})), (frozenset({'I1'}), frozenset({'I4'})), (frozenset({'I2'}), frozenset({'I3'})), (frozenset({'I2'}), frozenset({'I4'})), (frozenset({'I3'}), frozenset({'I4'}))]
```

and I want it to convert it to a list like below:

```
[ frozenset({'I1','I2'}), frozenset({'I1','I3'}),...]
```

tried convertion

```
data=[(frozenset({'I1'}), frozenset({'I2'})), (frozenset({'I1'}), frozenset({'I3'})), (frozenset({'I1'}), frozenset({'I4'})), (frozenset({'I2'}), frozenset({'I3'})), (frozenset({'I2'}), frozenset({'I4'})), (frozenset({'I3'}), frozenset({'I4'}))]
for x in data:
    for y in x:
        #tests
```

this is what I'm trying to make

```
[ frozenset({'I1','I2'}), frozenset({'I1','I3'}),...]
```

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```py
sets_lst = [(frozenset({'I1'}), frozenset({'I2'})), (frozenset({'I1'}), frozenset({'I3'})),
                   (frozenset({'I1'}), frozenset({'I4'})), (frozenset({'I2'}), frozenset({'I3'})),
                   (frozenset({'I2'}), frozenset({'I4'})), (frozenset({'I3'}), frozenset({'I4'}))]


result_lst = [frozenset().union(*curr_set_group) for curr_set_group in sets_lst]
```

Let me know if anything is unclear or if you have any questions!

Answer (score -2):

You want to [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) together the `frozenset`s in each tuple, then convert each of those chains to a `frozenset`

```
from itertools import chain
result = list(map(frozenset, map(chain.from_iterable, data)))
# [frozenset({'I1', 'I2'}), frozenset({'I1', 'I3'}), frozenset({'I1', 'I4'}), frozenset({'I3', 'I2'}), frozenset({'I2', 'I4'}), frozenset({'I3', 'I4'})]
```